# Comparison the data of two row and unique number highlight and show below of it

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in different sheets in one workbook, when I run macro in new workbook it ask the source workbook and bring it in one sheet(macro run workbook) compare the data of consequent row, if any number unique it will show below of it.

Comparison the data of consequent row and unique number show below of it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.